# Why is my second release is bigger than my first one?

Tags: vb.net, size

I made a project in VB.net and everything's working correctly. The only problem is that I noticed that after a little update of my software, the size have changed from **559kb** to **14.7mb** . Why ? I don't know. I did once add a .wav file to my resources but I removed it (Changed my mind). Is there a possibility that my .wav file is there floating somewhere in the backstage? Personally I think that's the problem because the song is **14mb**.

Edit: I removed the .wav file by going in My Project, Properties, Resources, Right click on the song file and Delete. I don't see it in either in the solution explorer (In resources folder).

Comment: It's fairly obvious that that WAV file is what's causing the increase in size but we can't really tell you what to do to get rid of it because your "description" of the problem is far too vague. We'd have to know EXACTLY what you did to add it and what you did to try to remove it in order to know what you did wrong.

Comment: BTW, the fact that you have no badges indicates that you rejected the invitation to take the site tour when you registered. If you spent some time learning how to use this site properly then you could have provided an appropriate question in the first place and you'd likely already have your answer. Visit the Help Center and do some reading on what's allowed and what's expected and then everything will go more smoothly.

Comment: Sorry. Im new on Stackoverflow and when I registered maybe I went to fast. I will check this.

Comment: What do you mean by "the size"?  Do you mean the size of a package to distribute, or do you mean the size of the project folder where you are developing?  If the latter, removing the resource from your project may not have deleted the file from your HDD.

Comment: After publishing the project on my desktop, the executable (software) is 14.7 mb.. It should be something like 770kb.